# Missing unicode code points for some vulgar fractions

Tags: unicode

At http://unicodefractions.com/ there's the following list of unicode code points representing vulgar fractions:

- VULGAR FRACTION 1/2  ½
- VULGAR FRACTION 1/3  ⅓
- VULGAR FRACTION 2/3  ⅔
- VULGAR FRACTION 1/4  ¼
- VULGAR FRACTION 3/4  ¾
- VULGAR FRACTION 1/5  ⅕
- VULGAR FRACTION 2/5  ⅖
- VULGAR FRACTION 3/5  ⅗
- VULGAR FRACTION 4/5  ⅘
- VULGAR FRACTION 1/6  ⅙
- VULGAR FRACTION 5/6  ⅚
- VULGAR FRACTION 1/7  ⅐
- VULGAR FRACTION 1/8  ⅛
- VULGAR FRACTION 3/8  ⅜
- VULGAR FRACTION 5/8  ⅝
- VULGAR FRACTION 7/8  ⅞
- VULGAR FRACTION 1/9  ⅑
- VULGAR FRACTION 1/10 ⅒

I would like to know why the following fractions are *missing* from this list:

- 2/7, 3/7, 4/7, 5/7, 6/7
- 2/9, 4/9, 5/9, 7/9, 8/9
- 3/10, 7/10, 9/10

Including them would result in a complete list of proper vulgar fractions with denominator in range [1..10]

Comment: I am not aware of any relevant documentation so can only guess. But I expect that only a limited unicode range was assigned for fractions so not all could be accommodated. Only the most commonly used were included. Decisions had to be made and they were. Naturally not everyone will agree. And as mentioned in the linked to article, you can create write these fractions with subscripts and superscripts.

Answer (score 1):

The current codepoints represent every fraction less than 1 with the denominator in range [1..6], as well as every fraction with a numerator of 1, and a denominator in range [1..10].  8ths were included because 8 = 2<sup>3</sup>, so they are used very often, and because only three additional fractions needed to be added to complete the list.  Adding 7ths or 9ths would require five additional fractions each, and they are used much less commonly.

That being said, I don't know why they didn't include 10ths.  9/10 is especially useful for writing gasoline prices.

The good news is, you can make them yourself using the fraction-slash, [U+2044](https://unicode-table.com/en/2044/).  The HTML code is `&frasl;`.  So `<sup>5</sup>&frasl;<sub>7</sub>` renders as <sup>5</sup>⁄<sub>7</sub>.  And sometimes, you don't even need the `<sup>` and `<sub>` tags, as some fonts will render any characters adjacent to the `&frasl;` as high or low automatically.

If you're not using one of those fonts, and you don't have access to HTML so you can only use individual unicode characters, you can use the superscript and subscript digits

You can find all the characters [here](https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/superscript-and-subscript-numbers/)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55033436/how-to-display-the-fraction-15-16-nicely-in-unicode & https://lights0123.com/fractions/